# Access Database -Creating a Data Input Form

Tags: forms, ms-access

I'm working on a Microsoft Access homework project. My question is: how to to make a data input form like:

"a. Construct a form that will collect sales data as input, and post it to the Sales table.  Try to determine how to lock the existing records in the involved tables, so that the data in those records cannot be modified in the Form.  In other words, the Form is to be used only for entering new sales and reviewing existing/previous sales, but not for altering existing records."

I've searched for tutorials on how to make forms but they are all extremely basic and don't provide enough details to help me reach the requested result. Is there a template or a design trace close to the requested form?

Comment: Check out the form properties on the "Data" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Set property *AllowEdits* of the form to *False*.

But this is bad design. When you have saved a new record and notice a typo or something, you can't edit it.